# Tuple Relational Calculus or Relational Algebra Syntax verifier?

Tags: math, relational

Does anybody knows of a software package where you can type a formula and it verifies sintactically (it doesn't need to check semantics).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I know of anything like this is an implementation of Tutorial D for relational database queries:

- [Rel](http://dbappbuilder.sourceforge.net/Rel.php)

Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for though.

Comment: It's not exactly of Relational Calculus but it'll be very helpfull for mi learning process.

Thanks!